# run the app in device it cashes without any crash reports and showing No Stack and it is working fine in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Whenever I run my application on the device it crashes without any crash reports and no strack trace.  It is working fine in the simulator.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: If there is no crash message then there is no point for us to start. Can you provide any more information, iOS version, iPhone version, Xcode version and what you have done to solve the problem. Have you checked the console (not the bedug console) and crash logs of the device?

Comment: Do you start the app with the Xcode Run button or from the device itself? I am aware that the question is quite basic, but it is a possible cause.

Comment: What do you want us to do with that so poor description ?

Comment: Ther description is poor because the problem is just as described. When there is a problem with the provisioning profile the app works fine in the simulator but will crash without any call stack or any sort of information when run on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most frequently happens when there is a problem with provisioning profiles. Check that they are current, and delete and reload them on your iOS device.

Answer (score -1):

With the information you have provided I can only suggest to:
Place a breakpoint in your code in `applicationDidFinishedLaunching` and debug line by line to check where it is crashing on device.